# Google Apps Script, select a sheet - Sets values in first sheet tab - not a specific sheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script provided seems to work, but it posts the data to the first sheet tab of the spreadsheet, when I'd like to have it post on a sheet entitled XML.

I've tried changing `getActiveSheet()` to `getSheetByName("XML")` and a number of other things but have had no luck. Any ideas?

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("http://www.resources-game.ch/exchange/kurseliste.xml?' + queryString + '","//RESOURCES_RATES/ITEM")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction1);

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change this line:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction1);
```

to this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName('XML').getRange('A1')
  .setValue(cellFunction1);
```

I added `getActiveSpreadsheet()`  which is different than `getActiveSheet()`.  There is also a `getActive()` method which gets a spreadsheet.  So, both `getActive()` and `getActiveSpreadsheet()` do the same thing.  They get the spreadsheet, not a sheet.  I've confused those 3 methods before.

- `getActive()`  - gets spreadsheet
- `getActiveSpreadsheet()`  - gets spreadsheet
- `getActiveSheet()`  - gets *sheet*